# Desaturate non-accent(tint) colored views when modals/alerts visible in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uicolor

iOS does a nice transition when modals and overlays are visible, desaturating the default tint/accent color in any views underneath that are still visible.

However, this isn't provided "for free" on other colors, nor for emoji in text labels. These colors can be equally bright... if not brighter.

Is there a preferred way to desaturate views perhaps at the entire view level when alert is visible? Is this a "worm hole" that isn't worth going down? Or, is it possible simply with perhaps a custom `ViewModifier` of some kind, or something?